# Swift alternative to write a lot of bools

Tags: swift, swift3

Let's say I have a class called Number and it has a `bool even` and a `bool big` (ignore the meanings of them).

I want to build a function that receives 2 Numbers **a** and **b** and do a different thing for all possibilities of their bools:

```
func tooMuchCodeToWrite(a: Number, b: Number){
    if(!a.even && !a.big && !b.even && !b.big){
        //do something
    }
    else if(!a.even && !a.big && !b.even && b.big){
        //do something
    }
    else if(!a.even && !a.big && b.even && !b.big){
        //do something
    }
    else if(!a.even && !a.big && b.even && b.big){
        //do something
    }

    // ...

    else if(a.even && a.big && b.even && !b.big){
        //do something
    }
    else{ //everyone is true in this case
        //do something
    }
}
```

is there a trick or a beautiful way to deal with this instead of writing all this code?

Comment: You might want to post this at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think it depends on what the `do something` entails.  Is it a function where you can use the value of the bools to calculate?  Can you shorten a few if's to the conditional operator?

Comment: Screams for `switch`...

Comment: @rmaddy: In its present form, this question would probably  get closed as "pseudo-code or example code" on CR.

Comment: as I said, each possibility does something different

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The typical solution to this kind of problem is a tuple-switch:

```
func tooMuchCodeToWrite(a: Number, b: Number){
    switch (a.even, a.big, b.even, b.big) {
    case (false, false, false, false): // ...
    case (false, false, false, true): // ...
    case (false, false, true, false): // ...
    ...
}
```

The nice thing about this approach is that it will check that you cover all the cases exactly once. The bad thing about this approach is there is nothing meaningful about each `true` and `false`, which can be confusing.

This approach also lends itself to grouping common "don't care" cases. For example, if you are always going to do the same thing if `a` is even, no matter all the other values, you can write:

```
case (true, _, _, _): // ...
```

While the position-dependence is still annoying, this has the benefit of expressing "don't care about these" very clearly.

You can make it a little more documenting this way:

```
switch (aeven: a.even, abig: a.big, beven: b.even, bbig: b.big) {
case (aeven: false, abig: false, beven: false, bbig: true): break
// ...
}
```

Swift won't force you to add the labels, but if you do add the labels, Swift will make sure that they're correct. This can get pretty verbose, so it's a trade-off if it helps or hurts.

Comment: I really liked the first way :) havent thought about it

Comment: By the way, in C we would probably do the same with a bitmap and masks. Can be still useful for array indexing.

Answer (score 1):

You could nest the individual tests:

```
if ( !a.even ) {
    if ( !a.big ) {
        if ( !b.even ) {
            if ( !b.big ) {
                //do something
            } else {
                //do something
            }
        } else {
            if ( !b.big ) {
                //do something
            } else {
                //do something
            }
        }
    } else {
...
```

No sure about more beautiful, but (slightly) more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
if (!a.even) {
    if (!a.big) {
        if (!b.even) {
            if (!b.big) {
                //Do Stuff
             }
             else {
                 //Do Stuff 
    .....
}
else {
    //if a.even
    ....
}
```

Comment: I had thought about this but its worse to see/understand where things happen